# HTML5 Responsive Images

Tags: html

What is the best solution for responsive images? The `img srcset` attribute, or the `<picture>` element? What is the difference?

http://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset
http://caniuse.com/#feat=picture

Is there a good lazy loader / responsive image jQuery plugin I could use, or some similar tool?

Just to show I did my homework:

- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#embedded-content
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/responsive/picture-element/
- http://html5doctor.com/responsive-images-end-of-year-report/
- http://timkadlec.com/2013/11/why-we-need-responsive-images-part-deux/

Comment: use twitter bootstrap

Comment: I'm talking about loading new images for different screen sizes, not resizing the default image. Bootstrap has no such component.

Comment: Here are two jQuery plugins I found that do exactly what I'm looking for: * [http://www.responsiveimg.com](http://www.responsiveimg.com) (Uses `<img>` tags) * [http://jquerypicture.com](http://jquerypicture.com) (Uses the new `<figure>` and `<picture>` elements as a sort of polyfill until those are widely supported.) I may push an update to one or both of those to use the new-ish [Media Querylist](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#mediaquerylist) function, which is much better performance-wise than $(window).resize();

Answer (score 0):

You can use css "display:flex;" just have to apply it to the parent of the image.

Comment: I'm talking about loading new images for different screen sizes, not resizing the default image.

Comment: Update your question please for clarification. And if i understand your question right you could do it with CSS and media queries, but if you want to do it with JQuery check this website: 
http://imulus.github.io/retinajs/

Comment: The reason for using JS over CSS is that we can load entirely separate images for different devices. This means the image will be smaller for mobile devices, and thus faster to load. My apologies for being unclear, but this answer has nothing to do with the `img srcset` functionality.

Comment: Yep got it now, and retina.js does not suit your needs?

Comment: No, because I'm thinking of **all** devices, not just retina.